# InfluxDB: Select latest values in ascending order

Tags: influxdb

To select the latest 100 data points from a measurement I use the following query:

```
select field1, field2 from measurement 
  where time < now() 
  order by time desc limit 100
```

However I need the values in ascending order. Currently I'm inverting the result in my application, which is costly.

I also tried a subquery, but without success:

```
select field1, field2 from 
  (select * from measurement 
     where time <= now() 
     order by time desc limit 100) order by asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query as a work out

```
select * from measurement where time <= now() and time >= now() - "some time you defined" limit 100
```

Though You have to cautious about your defining time.